# Laravel Eloquent - How to query NOT LIKE?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How might I find something that is not like a certain string.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT LIKE '%ray%';
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Simply you can use the model to get that result

```
User::where('username', 'not like', "%ray%")->get();
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a few different options depending on your needs. You can use any of the following to find something that is not like a certain string:

`Users::where('username', 'not like', "%ray%")->get();`

`DB::table('users')->where('username', 'not like', '%ray%');`

`Capsule::table('users')->select('*')->where('username', 'not like', '%ray%')->get();`

Answer (score 4):

Use DB facade

```
   $data = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('username', 'not like', '%ray%')->get();
```

Also you can use

```
 $data = User::where('username', 'not like', "%ray%")->get();
```